# latexdiff fails on description environments

Tags: lists, description, latexdiff

This example fails to generate a valid `.tex`:

#### `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[thing] explanation of thing
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

#### `test_modified.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[A first thing] an explanation of first thing
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Executing

```
latexdiff test.tex test_modified.tex > test_diff.tex  
pdflatex test_diff.tex
```

yields

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.                                            
l.25 ...
```

Here is the block of interest in the generated `.tex`:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \item[thing] %%%
\DIFdel{explanation of }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \item[A first thing] \DIFadd{an explanation of first }\DIFaddend thing
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

So `latexdiff` has inserted code *before* the `\item`, and the compiler does not like it.

Now the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/latexdiff.1.html) says `latexdiff` has options to exclude commands. I tried to add

```
--exclude-safecmd="\\\item"
```

in the command line invoking `latexdiff`, with no success.

Has anyone ever tweaked the options of `latexdiff` and could say how to circumvent the bug (e.g. tell `latexdiff` to skip this kind of environment)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I spent some more time looking for a way to solve this, and [the solution](http://w3.pppl.gov/~hammett/comp/tex/latexdiff.html) is to define a dummy command that does nothing:

```
\newcommand{\diffblock}[1]{#1}
```

Just put the whole description in this block:

```
\diffblock{
\begin{description}
    \item[A first thing] an explanation of first thing
\end{description}
}
```

And add `--append-safecmd="diffblock"` in the `latexdiff` options.

It understands it should treat it as a whole block and does not attempt to insert its own code inside the block.

Comment: I had to use `--exclude-safecmd="diffblock"` to get this working with an earlier version that did not have a `\diffblock{}` yet.

Comment: However the same might also be achieved without defining a \diffblock command but adding description to the PICTUREENV via --config="PICTUREENV=(?:picture|figure|DIFnomarkup|descripti‌​on)[\w\d*@]*". See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73224/is-there-an-option-in-latexdiff-to-ignore-whole-environments/73649?noredirect=1#comment804353_73649).
Moreover the problem seems to be gone in version 1.0.4.