# is there an option in latexdiff to ignore whole environments?

Tags: latexdiff

I need to highlight the difference between two rather complex math tex-files and get a lot of errors. The files are complex in the math equations, fair enough to get errors, but what if I would like `latexdiff` to only compare the text OUTSIDE the `\begin{align}` ... `\end{align}` environment? Can one specify to exclude/ignore certain environments?

Answer (score 53):

Yes there is a way to do this.  `latexdiff` has a class of environments that it regards as pictures and which it does not check.  The value is stored in `PICTUREENV` and its default is `(?:picture|DIFnomarkup)[\w\d*@]*`.  Writing a config file `ld.cfg` containing

```
PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|align)[\w\d*@]*
```

adds the `align` environment to this list.  If this config file is placed in the current directory you can now run

```
latexdiff -c ld.cfg old.tex new.tex >diff.tex
```

and the content of your `align` environments will now be ignored.

Comment: Note that you do not need to put it in a separate config file. You could also do `latexdiff --config="PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|align)[\w\d*@]*"`

Comment: @Rabarberski Indeed, remember double dash before `config`.  However, the command starts getting long and one has to be careful about escaping.

Comment: --config doesn't work for me from the Bash. I get `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Something went wrong in latexdiff. Deleting chp1/chp1-diff134.tex and abort`. What can I do?

Comment: @FrankBreitling In the shell you to either escape the many special characters or use single quotes instead.  It really is easier with a config file.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I tried single quotes too, with the same result. Oh, actually I was using latexdiff-svn. Seems like latexdiff-cv doesn't have this option.

Comment: As it turned out, this was a [bug](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues/58) which got resolved by the developer [ftilmann](https://github.com/ftilmann) after I reported it. Now it works as of version 1.2.0. For older version use the workaround with additonal single quotes like `latexdiff '--config="PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|align)[\w\d*@]*"'`.